# Poco Parent-Child relation lost Client-side

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco, parent-child, relationship

I have this scenario:

```
STRUCTURE : 
Entity A
 ChildEntity B

Assume this is data in my database 

A1
    (childs)
   B1
   B2
   B3
A2
    (childs)
   B4
   B5
   B6
```

Using linq to SQL. I want a list of `B` items 
with a reference to parents (`A` items)

Server side it's all right before my web service send back data to client

I got a structure like this:

```
B1
  A1
    (childs)
    B1
    B2
    B3
B2
  A1 (parent)
    (childs)
    B1
    B2
    B3
...
...
```

If I try to navigate the Graph all items seems to be in the right place.

Client side, after server serialization and client deserialization I have this situation:

```
B1
  A1 (parent)
    (childs)    
    B1
    B2
    B3
B2
  NULL
B3
  NULL
B4
  A2 (parent)
    (childs)
    B4
    B5
    B6
B5
  NULL
B6
  NULL
```

ONLY one of the childs of `A` items keeps the reference to the parent. I tried to look at XML generated both client and server side but couldn't find the problem.

Can anyone try to help me understand why this happens?
Or have a suggestion?

**NOTE :**
If I try to compress the list server side, as `byte[]`, and decompress it back client side, casting the compressed object to `List<B>`, all items maintain the correct relation also client side, everything is okay. So I imagine it's a problem in Serialization/Deserialization

I'm using:

- standard serialization (DataContractSerializer)
- standard microsoft POCO template
- EF4.

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was :
The XMLSerializer when serializing properties  puts them in the XML  apparently in random order (maybe it follows some order it gets from Datamodel edmx, i've not investigated about it)
So i got this scenario in XML generated by the XMLSerializer :

```
<b:CHILD_Entity **z:Id="i1"** xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <b:CHILD_ID>008acd9a-2074-46b0-b73b-90b8c9123f6f</b:CHILD_ID>
    <b:ReasonInfo>HRC->PLC 11</b:ReasonInfo>
    <b:StartTime>2011-11-29T09:22:36.553</b:StartTime>
    <b:EndTime>2011-11-29T10:31:58.507</b:EndTime>
    <b:Quantity>0</b:Quantity>
    <b:PARENT_Entity z:Id="i2">
        <b:Description i:nil="true"></b:Description>
        <b:UtilizationType>COMMITTED</b:UtilizationType>
        <b:Reason>SETUP</b:Reason>
        <b:ReasonInfo></b:ReasonInfo>
        <b:CHILD_Entities>
            <b:**CHILD_Entity** **z:Ref="i1"**></b:CHILD_Entity>
            <b:**CHILD_Entity** **z:Id="i3"** xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
                <b:CHILD_ID>008acd9a-2074-46b0-b73b-90b8c9123f6f</b:CHILD_ID>
                <b:ReasonInfo>HRC->PLC 11</b:ReasonInfo>
                <b:StartTime>2011-11-29T09:22:36.553</b:StartTime>
                **<b:ProductionCapabilityUtilization z:Ref="i2"></b:ProductionCapabilityUtilization>**
                ***<b:PARENT_ID>32864280-fe68-4b21-8375-b57ae8bbd7e6</b:PARENT_ID>***
                ..........
            </b:CHILD_Entity>
            ..................

        </b:CHILD_Entities>
        **<b:PARENT_ID>32864280-fe68-4b21-8375-b57ae8bbd7e6</b:PARENT_ID>**
    </b:PARENT_Entity>
    ***<b:PARENT_ID>32864280-fe68-4b21-8375-b57ae8bbd7e6</b:PARENT_ID>***
    <b:PROP1>MLM</b:PROP1>
    <b:PROP2>MLM1</b:PROP2>
    <b:Reason>RUN</b:Reason>
</b:CHILD_Entity>
<b:**CHILD_Entity** **z:Ref="i3"** xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"></b:CHILD_Entity>
```

the problem is that could happen that sometimes FIXUP generated code try to set PARENTID on CHILD_Entity before PARENT_Entity.PARENT_ID is set and after CHILD_Entity.PARENT_Entity SETTER was fired.
so we got a strange scenario where CHILD_Entity.PARENT has a value but CHILD_Entity.Parent.PARENT_ID = NULL because the DESERIALIZER has still not processed that property from the XML

To solve this kind of problems i had to modify POCO Template this way :

1. Set a counter variable  `int propertyPosCounter = 1;`
2. Specify ORDER when setting DataMemberAttribute 
     `[DataMemberAttribute(Order = <#=propertyPosCounter.ToString()#>)]`
3. Increment the counter after that `propertyPosCounter +=1;`
4. REPEAT This process for each **Primitive Properties** - **Complex Properties** - **Navigation Properties**
   in order we got always the right order in generated XML to Deserialize Client Size using POCO and it's Fixup concept

After this adjustemant to the POCO.tt template i solve those kind of conflicts and got no problems 
*Serializing -> Deserializing* my data structures passed from my WCF service to my client application
the result in the XML serialized is :

```
<b:CHILD_Entity z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <b:CHILD_ID>008acd9a-2074-46b0-b73b-90b8c9123f6f</b:CHILD_ID>
    <b:PARENT_ID>32864280-fe68-4b21-8375-b57ae8bbd7e6</b:PARENT_ID>
    <b:PROP1>MLM</b:PROP1>
    <b:PROP2>MLM1</b:PROP2>
    <b:Reason>RUN</b:Reason>
    <b:ReasonInfo>HRC->PLC 11</b:ReasonInfo>
    <b:StartTime>2011-11-29T09:22:36.553</b:StartTime>
    <b:EndTime>2011-11-29T10:31:58.507</b:EndTime>
    <b:Quantity>0</b:Quantity>
    <b:PARENT_Entity z:Id="i2">
        <b:PARENT_ID>32864280-fe68-4b21-8375-b57ae8bbd7e6</b:PARENT_ID>
        <b:Description i:nil="true"></b:Description>
        <b:UtilizationType>COMMITTED</b:UtilizationType>
        <b:Reason>SETUP</b:Reason>
        <b:ReasonInfo></b:ReasonInfo>
        <b:CHILD_Entity>
            <b:CHILD_Entity z:Ref="i1"></b:CHILD_Entity>
            <b:**CHILD_Entity** **z:Id="i3"** xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
                <b:CHILD_ID>008acd9a-2074-46b0-b73b-90b8c9123f6f</b:CHILD_ID>
                ***<b:PARENT_ID>32864280-fe68-4b21-8375-b57ae8bbd7e6</b:PARENT_ID>***
                <b:ReasonInfo>HRC->PLC 11</b:ReasonInfo>
                <b:StartTime>2011-11-29T09:22:36.553</b:StartTime>
                ..........
                **<b:ProductionCapabilityUtilization z:Ref="i2"></b:ProductionCapabilityUtilization>**
            </b:CHILD_Entity>
        </b:CHILD_Entity>
    </b:PARENT_Entity>
</b:CHILD_Entity>
```

I tried to be as clear as possible but the scenario is not trivial, so if anyone needs clarification do not hesitate to ask for it, i will try to answer as soon as i can.

Hope this post could help someone else :)

Regards,
Luigi Martinez Bianchi

Comment: Great solution... I'd faced this problem and the same reason about a year ago but at that time could not come to the solution you mentioned. I simply changed the poco template to check the primary key of the parent object and if it was null, prevented the change to affect foreign key property.  Your solution is elegant and I'll use it in my code.  
ps: please mark your own post as answer, so others know that it's the correct answer.